# Using mdadm, is it possible to change copy number in Raid10 array?

Tags: raid, mdadm

I am attempting to finally setup a raid10 array for my media collection to use on a dedicated server box. I had no experience using mdadm, but followed the tutorial at:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04
It was thorough and very helpful. However, I failed to look closely at what I was doing, and failed to modify their code properly for my own purposes. Specifically I entered this:

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=10 --layout=n3 --raid-devices=6 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sdf /dev/sdg
```

my intention would have been to enter it this way:

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=10 --layout=n2 --raid-devices=6 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sdf /dev/sdg ​
```

> ```
>    ~$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0:
> ```
>
> > ```
> >    Version : 1.2
> >    Creation Time : Sun Apr  2 14:03:20 2017
> >    Raid Level : raid10
> >    Array Size : 11720661504 (11177.69 GiB 12001.96 GB)
> >    Used Dev Size : 3906887168 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
> >    Raid Devices : 6
> >    Total Devices : 6
> >    Persistence : Superblock is persistent
> >
> >
> >    Intent Bitmap : Internal
> >
> >
> >    Update Time : Sun Apr  9 10:40:43 2017  
> >    State : clean, degraded, recovering   
> >    Active Devices : 5  
> >    Working Devices : 6  
> >    Failed Devices : 0  
> >    Spare Devices : 1  
> >
> >
> >    Layout : near=2
> >    Chunk Size : 512K
> >
> >
> >    Rebuild Status : 2% complete
> >
> >
> >    Name : Marx:0  (local to host Marx)
> >    UUID : 412e2c9d:c4239440:5fa7a2b5:69b9353a
> >    Events : 32540
> >
> >
> >    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice    State  
> >    0       8        0        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sda  
> >    1       8       16        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdb  
> >    2       8       32        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdc  
> >    6       8       80        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sdf  
> >    7       8       96        4      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdg  
> >    5       8       48        5      active sync set-B   /dev/sdd
> > ```

I have three sets of two mirrors and only 7.3T available instead of roughly 12T as intended.

> > > ```
> > >    ~$ df -h -x devtmpfs -x tmpfs
> > > ```
> > >
> > > > ```
> > > >    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
> > > >    /dev/sde2       102G  6.6G   91G   7% /  
> > > >    /dev/sde1       511M  3.6M  508M   1% /boot/efi  
> > > >    /dev/md0        7.3T  6.6T  343G  96% /media/sharemore
> > > > ```

Quick aside: /dev/sdg had some sort of small partition that I did not see when I formed the array. After a reboot, it was dropped form the /md0 array. My pseudo-educated guess is that there was some interference on that partition that was not allowing the Superblock on that hard disk to be read/seen. I was able to use the disks utility to delete all partitions on /sdg. I then had to force the reassembly without the /sdg disk which successfully rebuilt the array (with 5/6 disks present) I then was able to add the /sdg back into the /md0 array, causing the rebuilding (to fill in the third copy of 'A').

Really sorry for the long winded setup. Here is my question:
Once this rebuild is complete and if it shows all six devices as active-sync, is there a means to change the layout to be --layout=n2 without losing the data?

Appreciate any help you can provide.

Cheers.

Comment: I think this is possible but I am not confident enough in the mdadm usage to write a complete answer.  Generally you are looking for mdadm "Reshape" commands.. you should in theory be able to remove two of the mirrors and then add them back in, finally resizing the filesystem.  Probably a little fiddly and error-prone.  Most good examples seem to deal largely with RAID5.